# C# how to read a list of strings at runtime

Tags: c#, arrays, string, dynamic, runtime

I am a new C# user and currently have a hardcoded string array, I want this to be available for an end user to change without having to recompile the code (as more revisions become available in future):

```
public static string[] SheetNameString = new string[]
    {
        "VERSION3.7.1",
        "VERSION3.7.2",
        "VERSION3.7.2.3",
        "VERSION3.7.3",
        "VERSION3.8",
        "VERSION3.8.1",

        "Remove - item was closed"
    };
```

How would you go about achieving this.  I thought about defining a text file which gets read in the executing bin folder and then at execution time each line defined in the text file is assigned into the list as an element:

```
List<string> SheetNameString = new List<string>();
```

Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: That's reasonable. Check into File.ReadAllLines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, I will try this way out as its simple and likely to get the job done

Answer (score 0):

What you should use is the `App.config`utility.
Here's a good article about how to use it.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616065/Why-Where-and-How-of-NET-Configuration-Files

Comment: Not sure it's a great idea for an end user to be editing an app.config, possibly depending on who your end users are. It's not completely clear on what he's looking for though.

Comment: I was about to ask if this was a bit beyond the scope of an end user, the idea is that they can easily add new versions to the end of a file that is already in place.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the use case.  If you have multiple users, You should probably store this in a Database Table.  Your code will then read in the contents of that table (using Entity Framework or NHibernate most likely), present it for the user, and allow basic CRUD operations.

For a single user console/windows app, you could store this in a file, read it in, and update as needed.